# Fillter by color in Libre Calc

Tags: libreoffice

i have given background colors for certain rows that i have verified. but the problem  is i cant filter the particular rows using the color in libre calc

Is there any option by which we can filter rows using the background color of the rows?

Answer (score 0):

A quick bit of research provided this response:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269321/libreoffice-calc-openoffice-calc-how-to-filter-rows-based-on-their-background

It suggests that there is no built in function but lists a macro which could form the basis of the task you are considering.